# write in all lines plus one

Tags: shell-scripting, count

Can you help me with a unix script to get result like this in file:

```
apple1
apple2
apple3
```

etc.. till 100

from a file apple.txt which contains only one word - apple.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: shortest solution echo ; seq -f`<apple.txt`%g 100

Comment: Is the leading blank line relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we're all piling in with ideas, here's mine, with my long-time favourite under-used command, `seq`:

```
echo "" ; apple=`cat /tmp/apple.txt` ; seq 1 100 | sed -e "s/^/$apple/"
```

The `echo` at the beginning provides your intial blank line, which I fear some posters may be forgetting about (though their solutions are perfectly good, and could all be be easily fixed, hint hint).

Comment: `seq` is not Unix, UUoC, sed use for no good reason. This is pretty much the WORST of all possible answers.

Comment: Forgive me, but in what sense is `seq` not UNIX, if `bash` is?  It's part of the GNU coreutils set of tools, which includes other things that I personally regard as absolutely core UNIX tools (`rm`?  `mv`?).  I agree that I could have done without `sed` if I'd known about `seq`'s format option (see ThorstenS's excellent answer), but I didn't, so I'm learning from this whole thing, too.  I can't quite see how I could have loaded the file into the variable without cat, so may I just add that I'm interested to see how you're going to do this without using `bash`, `sh`, or `seq`?

Comment: Bash isn't POSIX or SUS either :)

Comment: True, but the OP didn't ask for POSIX compliancy, only for a UNIX solution.  If you'd like to ask a new question that requires POSIX, we'll see what we can do!

Comment: See my answer for the most efficient bash solution.

Answer (score 3):

Google has ample resources for Bash Scripting.

Anyways here goes:

```
for i in {1..100}; do echo "`cat apple.txt`$i"; done
```

Comment: bad idea to cat 100 times :-/

Comment: @ThorstenS is right: `for i in $(< apple.txt){1..100}; do echo "$i"; done`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution in [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
awk '{ while (count++ < 100) print $0 count }' apple.txt > output.txt
```

---

Bonus [seq-golf](https://serverfault.com/a/374233/82757) solution (29 characters):

```
seq -f"$(pg apple.txt)%g" 100
```

`seq` starts at 1 by default, so there is no need to specify the `FIRST` parameter. The example output does not pad the numbers, so the format can be reduced. From the looks of the markup, the blank line in the example output is probably a formatting error.

Edit (25 characters): `seq -f$(<apple.txt)%g 100`

Comment: seq -f"$(<apple.txt)%g" 100

Comment: Solution destroyed almost instantly. Nice!

Comment: Quotes are unnecessary! `seq -f$(<apple.txt)%g 100`

Comment: 24chars: seq -f`<apple.txt`%g 100

Comment: @ThorstenS I can't think of anything shorter.

Comment: Nice, though I don't think the first-blank-line requirement is a formatting error - look at the title of the question (... all lines **plus one**).

Comment: Ah, I assumed that was referring to the incremental output.

Comment: @mteckert, you do need the quotes to cover the case that "apple.txt" contains whitespace.

Comment: The first line can be managed in AWK with a conditional expression such as in `awk '{while (i<101) {print (i?$1 i:""); i++}}' apple.txt > output.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
seq --format "$(cat apple.txt)%02g" 1 100
```

Comment: ok: seq -f "$(cat apple.txt)%02g" 1 100

Comment: Very short, though no initial blank line, and not the number format the OP asked for in the 1-9 range.  And yaay you for using seq!

Comment: mea culpa- here it goes: echo -e; seq --format "$(cat apple.txt)%g" 1 100

Comment: <grin> no worries, i missed it first time around, too!  +1 for you!

Answer (score 0):

If `bash` is available, the following uses no external commands:

```
( read -r t; for i in {1..100}; do echo "$t$i" >> outfile; done ) < apple.txt
```

Comment: I think you missed the first (empty) line.

Comment: I see nothing that requires one.